# Glyphicon para bootstrap 4 não funciona

Tags: bootstrap-glyphicons

Estou usando essa Cdn para o link do css do Glyphicon, o problema é que estou usando o bootstrap 4, e por isso está dando conflito, qual seria o url certa do **Glyphicon**?

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css
```

Comment: glyphicons só funcionam com a versão 3 do bootstrap! na versão 4 tem que usar outra coisa como o font-awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente essa aqui, cole ela dentro da tag  antes de todos seus links css:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">`